# Dependency errors when configuring BlueZ on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, bluez

When trying trying to follow the [bluez/HACKING](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/d764f78f27653bc1df71c462e9aca7a18bc75f9f/HACKING#L82) guide for installing BlueZ in development mode on Raspberry Pi OS (Bullseye) I get a variety of errors:

```bash
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git
cd bluez
./bootstrap-configure
```

Errors include:

```bash
./bootstrap: 5: libtoolize: not found
```

```bash
configure: error: elfutils support is required
```

```bash
configure: error: ALSA lib is required for MIDI support
```

Comment: The command `sudo apt-get build-dep bluez` will, as root, install all dependencies for 'bluez' so that it can be built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 07/05/2023

[@ukBaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76606527/compiling-errors-when-installing-bluez-on-raspberry-pi?noredirect=1#comment135071744_76606527) pointed out that you can instead use `sudo apt-get build-dep bluez` to install all the necessary dependencies.

However on Raspberry Pi OS this may give you the error: `E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list`. To resolve:

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and uncomment the line with `deb-src`.
2. Run `sudo apt-get update`
3. Run `sudo apt update`
4. Now run `sudo apt-get build-dep bluez`

### Previous Answer

BlueZ requires a variety of dependencies and so if you don't have these installed you'll get those errors. Below is a (uncomprehensive) list of errors you might encounter and how to fix them:

| Error | Solution |
| --- | --- |
| `libtoolize: not found` | `sudo apt install libtool` |
| `configure: error: ALSA lib is required for MIDI support` | `sudo apt-get install libalsa-ocaml-dev` |
| `configure: error: elfutils support is required` | `sudo apt-get install libelf-dev elfutils libdw-dev` |
| `configure: error: SBC library >= 1.2 is required` | `sudo apt-get install libsbc-dev` |
| `configure: error: SPEEXDSP library >= 1.2 is required` | `sudo apt-get install libspeexdsp-dev` |